# Horizontal justification for the side comments, in Tufte-Handout style.

Tags: tufte

I am using Tufte handout template and I see that many of the margin comments (figure captions, footnotes, citations, etc) are not justified/aligned. I was wondering if there is an easy fix for this.

[image]

Comment: Which options have you passed to `\documentclass`? If you passed the `justified` option, then the body text and marginal text should both be fully justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `justified` option in `\documentclass`

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
```

[image]

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[justified]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\section{Main text}
\sidenote[][-3cm]{sidenotes\\ This is a justified side note. This is a justified side note. This is a justified side note. This is a justified side note. This is a justified side note } \cite{dirac}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{marginfigure}
\rule{\textwidth}{2.6cm}
\caption{Caption of a figure that is aligned properly. Caption of a figure that is aligned properly. Caption of a figure that is aligned properly. Caption of a figure that is aligned properly. Caption of a figure that is aligned properly. }
\label{fig:marginfig}
\end{marginfigure}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: saved my life for the 2nd time